# How to centre drawable vertically in TextInputLayout?

Tags: android, material-design, android-textinputlayout, material-components, material-components-android

I have added a drawable on the left side of the TextInputLayout (as seen in TextInputEditText below) and want to add some padding below  it such that it becomes centred vertically inside its parent. Is there a command or a workaround for this?

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/contact_first_name_input_text"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="@string/contact_first_name"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/contactFirstName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_person_black_24dp"
                    android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                    />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the **`app:startIconDrawable`** attribute in your `TextInputLayout` to add a drawable:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
       app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/..."
```

[image][image]

Comment: Thank you Gabriele, I did the mistake of using android:DrawableStart in TextInputEditText!

Comment: how I can make the icon at the end of the view (in the other direction of the image you posted) ?

Comment: @Amin https://stackoverflow.com/a/62576309/2016562