# How to add a drawable at the right end of a "TextInputLayout" dynamically?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android

I am trying to make something like this example:

[image: Screenshot of a user name text field with a check suffix icon]

I want the drawable to show when I verify the user name from the server.

I am using Material Design Text Input Field & EditText. Yes, I can do it with a simple `EditText` and an `ImageView`, but I want to use the standard elements.

I have looked at the official documentation, there is a way to add the image at the Right corner using XML, but I want to add it programmatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to to set your drawable programmatically like below

```
inputTextEditText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.drawableRight), null)
```

Comment: Thanks, the drawable is added but now the text is overlapping the left icon. Here is the screenshot : https://ibb.co/5j5N5nZ

Comment: for that may you need to add padding start on it.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I fixed it with "setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds"

Comment: @MehulKabaria  It is not correct. Using the `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds` on the `TextInputEditText` != to use `app:endIconDrawable` (official way) in the layout. Check also the official doc: **Note:** You should opt to use the `EndIconMode` API instead of setting an end/right compound `Drawable` on the `TextInputEditText`

Answer (score 19):

Use the **`setEndIconDrawable`** method:

```
    textInputLayout.setEndIconDrawable(R.drawable.xxxx);
    textInputLayout.setEndIconMode(TextInputLayout.END_ICON_CUSTOM);
```

or in a layout:

```
  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/xxxxx"
        app:endIconMode="custom"
```

[image]

More info in the [official doc](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TextField.md#adding-a-trailing-icon-to-a-text-field).